# How to import all images from folder in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, bundler, parceljs

I have 1000 images in folder and I have to import all those images to project. I tried this:

```
import images from './img/*.jpg
```

It works just fine on localhost but when I try to deploy it on remote server it throws an error:

```
 Build failed.
8:44:50 AM: @parcel/core: Failed to resolve './../img/*.jpg' from './src/js/model.js'
8:44:50 AM:   /opt/build/repo/src/js/model.js:1:18
8:44:50 AM:   > 1 | import imgs from './../img/*.jpg';
8:44:50 AM:   >   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
8:44:50 AM:     2 | import { AMOUNT_OF_IMAGES } from './config.js';
8:44:50 AM:     3 |
8:44:50 AM: @parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file '../img/*.jpg' in './src/js'.
8:44:50 AM:  Did you mean '../img/1.jpg'?
8:44:50 AM:  Did you mean '../img/2.jpg'?
```

My package.json:

```
{
    "default": "index.html",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "parcel index.html",
        "build": "parcel build index.html -d ./dist --no-minify"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@parcel/transformer-image": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
        "parcel": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
        "parcel-bundler": "1.12.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "core-js": "^3.18.0",
        "img": "^3.0.3",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9"
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "import images into project" even mean?  FYI, the Javascript keyword `import` does not accept wildcards in the filename.  The `import` keyword must point to a single module file.

Comment: I think you have to import them one by one.

Comment: Check out this documentation: https://v2.parceljs.org/features/dependency-resolution/#glob-specifiers

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to actually import the image URLs into your app, so that you can render them in html - is that right?

If so, here's how you do it:

1. Make sure you've installed `@parcel/transformer-image` and `@parcel/resolver-glob` into your project.
2. Opt into [glob specifiers](https://v2.parceljs.org/features/dependency-resolution/#glob-specifiers) by adding a `.parcelrc` file to the root of your project with these entries:

   ```
   {
       "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
       "resolvers": ["@parcel/resolver-glob", "..."]
   }
   ```
3. (assuming that you actually want the urls of the images in your JS code - see above), write your import like this:

   ```js
   import images from "url:./images/*.jpg";
   ```

   The `images` object at runtime will look like this:

   ```js
   {
      "[fileName1]": "[path to fileName1.jpg]",
      "[fileName2]": "[path to fileName2.jpg]",
   }
   ```
4. You could render the `images` object with a framework of your choice. Here's how you would do it in React:

   ```
   const App = () => (
    <div>
      <h1>Images Imported with Glob Import</h1>
      {Object.entries(images).map(([imageName, imageUrl]) => (
        <div key={imageUrl}>
          <h2>{imageName}</h2>
          <img src={imageUrl} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
   );
   ```

You can see a working example in [this repo](https://github.com/astegmaier/parcel-images-glob)

**Edit**:
I also noticed something weird in your `package.json` that you might want to fix - you've included both parcel v2 (`parcel`) *and* parcel v1 (`parcel-bundler`). I'd recommend removing v1 and re-installing to make sure your `parcel` commands are indeed running v2. (The example above assumes you are running v2).